# "Abstract away from": disregarding details in effort to reach higher general and overarching notion of something

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, translation

I am a native Danish speaker. The Danish definition of the verb [**abstract**](https://ordnet.dk/ddo/ordbog?query=abstrahere) translates to *"disregarding the subordinate details in an effort to build a general, overarching notion of something"*. Thus, the verb gives connotations of something elevated, refined or pure. When translating my dictionary suggests *"abstract"*, *"disregard"*, or *"abstract away from"*. The [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) has almost no entries for the term "abstract away", while my gut felling tells me that the connotations associated with *"disregard"* is not quite right (i.e. "ignore" or "make light of").

Example:

> We *abstract away from* the specific mechanism and instead consider a general setting, where ...

I am open to rewriting the entire sentence, but I am unsure how to capture the feeling of something elevated, refined or pure, i.e. lifting it to a higher level. Or can I write "abstract away from"?

Comment: In English, _abstract_ in this sense refers to making a summary of a work such as a scientific paper so that a researcher will know whether it would be useful to read the whole thing. It doesn't have any connotations of refinement or purity.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'In Danish, the verb _abstract_ translates to "disregarding the subordinate details in an effort to build a general, overarching notion of something" ' means. // _However_, the way I'd put "disregard the subordinate details in an effort to build a general, overarching notion of something" is "give the quintessential details [of a matter]". _Quintessence_  has meanings including 'central sense, essence' and 'a refined extract' (see Lexico). // 'Abstract away from' is at best unidiomatic.

Comment: We **move** away from the specific mechanism and instead consider a general setting, where ...* Also *"disregard / gloss over / set aside / put to one side* the specific mechanism"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. You are right, and I've edited the sentence to clarify that it is the definition of the verb _abstract_ which I translate.

Answer (score 2):

The verb *to abstract* is used in English in the way that the OP describes. Even though this way of using is likely to be found only in the contexts of theoretical nature, it is listed in the widely available, general-purpose dictionaries, such as [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/abstract)

> abstract something from
>
> Consider something theoretically or separately from (something else)
>
> ‘to abstract science and religion from their historical context can lead to anachronism’

and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstract)

> abstract
>
> to consider apart from application to or association with a particular instance

This way of using the verb calls for the preposition *from*. While saying *to abstract away from* would not be incorrect, *away* seems redundant, as it doesn't really add anything to *to abstract from*.

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting and difficult question.  The first thing to say is that the use of 'abstract' as a verb is uncommon in English.  The past form, 'abstracted' is applied as a description of someone whose mind is on other things, or removed from the world around them. I normally expect that Danes know English at least as well as I do.  The Danish word is closer to its Latin root 'abstraho' than the English, which reflects the supine form of that verb, which means 'I draw/drag away' or 'remove'.

The nearest I can get to your fascinating Danish usage is the noun '*abstract*', which is an academic term for the summary of an academic paper or thesis or dissertation, which summarises the ***essence*** of the paper, without any of the detailed arguments beyond their general character.  So it does not apply to the sort of thing for which you are looking either.  It is something 'withdrawn' or 'taken away' from it.  Of course the adjective '*abstract*' gets us a bit closer.  Abstract things are *removed* from everyday tangible reality.  We talk, similarly, of *abstract* art, and we can certainly talk of discussing things or plans '*in the abstract*', meaning in a *theoretical* way.

Looking at Roget's wonderful Thesaurus, I do not get much further.  The verb can be used for to 'take away' 'shorten' or 'be concise'.

The full Oxford English Dictionary gets me a little bit closer to what you are looking for.

> To withdraw, deduct, remove or take away something.  So Boyle in 1685 gives us:  "having <dephlagoned?> spirit of salt and gently **abstracted** the whole spirit, there remaineth in the retort a ???? substance."  (my apologies that my failing eyesight and magnifying glass cannot get me to see every word in this miniaturised OED!).

In 1690, John Locke in his *On Human Understanding *is saying:

> Truth and Certainty of Moral Discourses abstracts from the Lives of Men."

This is getting a bit nearer the mark, but is still not quite there and takes us back nearly 350 years!.

Better is the definition:

> To separate in mental conception; to consider apart from the physical manifestation.

This surely is on the money for you.  Citations go back the the sixteenth century and the latest is from the late 19th century, and they apply to logic and reasoning.

> To abstract is to separate the qualities common to all individuals from the peculiarities of each individual. (Jevons *Elements of Logic* 1870)

So I am afraid I have failed and I cannot suggest an alternative word for the Danish.  Could it be, I wonder, that this is one of those beautiful places where one language (here Danish) has a word that has a useful meaning for which another language (here English) has no equivalent?

Comment: I am sure that there is something desperately wrong with the answer above.  The mystery is, however, that I have a minus-one (-1) against the above answer, but my score record tells me I have plus-six.  I suppose it is the result of 10-4 or something like that.  It doesn't matter, but i am baffled.